# Bazel runs very slowly

Tags: grpc, bazel

I have a relatively simple Bazel project which has the following:

- 2 proto files (B.proto depends on A.proto)
- Go/C++ libraries produced from these proto files with grpc support (used grpc/protobuf rules imported from [pubref/rules_protobuf](https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf))
- Server/client applications against these protos written in C++ and Go.

When I run bazel for the first time, it takes a LOT of time to execute. It compiles grpc, protobuf etc, which makes sense.

However, when I immediately run the compile again, my build takes ~80s even in the incremental case. For a project which is so simple, I would have expected much faster performance - especially since speed is said to be Bazel's primary advantage.

From what I can tell, the performance of my bazel builds was pretty fast until I incorporated grpc/protos.

Here's some information reported by bazel's profiler. I am unable to see any smoking guns in the profiler output.

One possible difference is that my builds run on an ubuntu docker container hosted on a macbook. The macos docker implementation runs on a lightweight hyperkit VM. So this is not a native build. But I would still not expect things to be this slow!

Phase Summary Information

- Total launch phase time   101 ms  0.12%
- Total init phase time 11.560 s    13.67%
- Total loading phase time  282 ms  0.33%
- Total analysis phase time 15.2 ms 0.02%
- Total preparation phase time  1.002 s 1.19%
- Total execution phase time    71.549 s    84.63%
- Total finish phase time   30.9 ms 0.04%
- Total run time    84.540 s    100.00%

Init Phase Information

- Total init time   11.560 s
- Total time (across all threads) spent on:

  - Type    Total   Count   Average
  - VFS_STAT  88.18%  12223   166 ms
  - VFS_DIR   10.49%  785 307 ms
  - VFS_READLINK  0.81%   221 84.4 ms
  - VFS_OPEN  0.01%   2   109 ms
  - VFS_READ  0.01%   4   28.7 ms

Execution Phase Information

- Total preparation time    1.002 s
- Total execution time  71.549 s
- Total finish time 30.9 ms
- Action dependency map creation    0.00 ms
- Actual execution time 71.549 s
- Total time (across all threads) spent on:

  - Type    Total   Count   Average
  - ACTION  0.00%   1   2.09 ms
  - ACTION_CHECK    0.00%   1   0.71 ms
  - ACTION_EXECUTE  0.00%   1   1.53 ms
  - INFO    0.00%   1   0.00 ms
  - VFS_STAT    39.71%  1803    26.3 ms
  - VFS_DIR 0.02%   2   14.0 ms
  - VFS_READLINK    0.36%   18  23.9 ms
  - VFS_MD5 0.00%   1   1.45 ms
  - VFS_DELETE  0.00%   1   1.44 ms
  - VFS_OPEN    0.02%   5   4.30 ms
  - VFS_READ    0.00%   4   0.48 ms
  - VFS_WRITE   0.00%   2   0.32 ms
  - SKYFRAME_EVAL   0.03%   1   31.0 ms
  - SKYFUNCTION 0.02%   5   5.83 ms
  - Critical path (25.7 ms):
  - Id  Time    Share   Description
  - 15078   25.7 ms 100.00% action 'BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the same build on an AWS EC2 instance. There the incremental build is substantially faster. So I am assuming the slowness is because of some filesystem issue due to running inside VM.